# Module not found error when file exists in same directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I am running python 3-32 bits on my windows computer. And here is my directory structure:

```
device_controller
  device_controller.py
  kestrel_main.py
```

And in the device_controller.py file, I have the import line as so:

```
from kestrel_main import mainKestrel
```

And I do have a mainKestrel() function defined in the kestrel_main.py file.

However, whenever I try to run the device_controller.py script, I get a `"ModuleNotFoundError: no module name kestrel_main"`.

I run the script by typing the absolute path of the python 3-32bit executable followed by "device_controller.py". So as in

```
{absolute path of python} device_controller.py
```

Any ideas on why I get this error?

Comment: put a full stop before the script name to say it is in the same folder: `from .kestrel_main import mainKestrel`

Comment: i got an "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package". Do I now have to add an init.py?

Comment: It is ok to import files like this, however, my guess is it's an issue with your python environment configuration. perhaps rather than specifying the absolute path of python, make a virtual environment in that directory and use that. Windows especially can be funky.

Comment: @TomMcLean relative imports without parent packages (no __init__ ) is not valid.

Comment: You could try: from device_controller.kesterel_main but that isn't great and is an indication your execution environment has issues.

Comment: guess it's a problem with my windows. I will try setting up a venv, because none of the above approaches is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have incorrectly installed python3-32. I would suggest removing the download files from your computer and then re-downloading. But make sure you download the installer and not the zipped file. After you do this, either add python to the path or reference the absolute path to python.exe every time you run your script.

Your current method of importing the module is correct.